# Are resource questions on-topic? If not, why keep the tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was thinking of asking a question about an introduction to Archaic English (in order to read poetry more fluently). But given that eight out of nine [resources](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) questions have been closed, I'm not sure if it would be on-topic.

I've seen  favorable opinions towards resources questions  [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/are-questions-asking-for-resources-on-topic), but is it still the case?

If not, wouldn't it be better to remove the tag or specify they are not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

I edited this tag out of all questions and it will be automatically deleted soon. It's not a useful tag, since resource requests are off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I could see a small use for the tag in asking questions related to *usage* or *study* of resources from a learner's perspective. Something like:

> "Why do dictionaries not generally assign unique ID numbers to words/concepts, while a thesaurus would?"

I'm not really sure of the topicality of that question, but it's the best I  can come up with right now. The point is, while I can't come up with a good question of that sort right now, I'm sure someone could. I wouldn't say that the tag needs to be blacklisted, since there are only 8 questions that use it. It's not like there's a flood of junk posts associated with it, so it's probably safe to let it stay for now.

Asking for resource *suggestions/recommendations* is explicitly off-topic.

Do note also that we have a [Meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english) with a fairly comprehensive set of resources. Any new questions that get asked about "what resources" should include a link to that canonical post along with the closevote.

Comment: For that hypothetical question, the [tag:learning] tag could serve as an inexact substitute that doesn't give the impression that asking for resources is OK.

Comment: In my opinion, if it is difficult to imagine questions where the tag is meaningful, that tag is not useful. Tags should help the searcher find relevant questions and if it's not really clear what the tag represents, non-native speakers are going to have trouble deciding whether it applies to their search. There may be some questions where it is the perfect tag, but I'm guessing that a more widely useful tag could be almost as good. I think it's easy to lose sight of the goal and get caught up categorizing everything perfectly instead of in the way it is most searchable.

Comment: I think something like *reference-materials* (or the existing *dictionaries*) would be a much better tag for your hypothetical question than *resources*.